# SQL Query person who belongs to many departments in the same time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say that I have the following table:

```
     id | person_id | department_id
    ------------------------------
      1 | 1         | 2
      2 | 1         | 3
      3 | 1         | 4
      4 | 3         | 2
      5 | 3         | 5
      6 | 5         | 4
      7 | 6         | 4
      8 | 9         | 4
```

I would like to query the person who belong to array of departments in the same time. 
for example: the person who belong to (2,5) departments is person 3 and he is the only person.

I searched a lot and tried to do it myself but I couldn't find a way.

p.s. I already done it with 'for' loop but I'm looking for fast and native SQL solution.

Comment: Question is bit unclear, please elaborate it with example input and output.

Comment: I will provide the array of departments id to the sql query and I should get person_id who belongs to all departments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select t.person_id
from followingtable t
where t.department_id in (2, 5)
group by t.person_id
having count(*) = 2;
```